# <xdr:absoluteAnchor> shape moves with DOCX4J in excel

Tags: java, excel, docx4j

I used docx4j for excel implementation.

By using code I drew text frame , then a table and then again a text frame.

I used xdr:absoluteAnchor instead of xdr:twoCellAnchor.

But i noticed that my last (3rd) text frame is moved slightly down.

Is there any way to avoid such shape auto re-placement(auto movement) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a text frame in Excel which behaves as you wish, then create corresponding Java code, which you can do by feeding your sample xlsx into http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html

For more help, you'll need to add the XML to your question.